# Partial sum and subtraction (minus) in UNION Query

Tags: mysql, union, subtraction

I have two similar tables (one for bills, the other payments) right now I show to users a union mixing data from both..

```
Table Bills                             
CustomerId  Amount                      
1           100                        
2           100                        
1           100                        
2           100

Table Payments
CustomerId  Amount
1           100
2           100
1           100
```

Right now my users can see the following informtation

```
From Customer 1
Type    CustomerId   Amount
B       1            100
P       1            -100
B       1            100
P       1            -100
TOTAL 0

From Customer 2
Type    CustomerId   Amount
B       1            100
P       1            -100
B       1            100
Total 100
```

Everything works fine using UNION Statement

Right now I need to show Partial Balance on each record so users can keep in mind balanca while they are looking at records..

Like this... (DESIRED)

```
From Customer 1
Type    CustomerId   Amount    Partial
B       1            100       100
P       1            -100      0
B       1            100       100
P       1            -100      0
```

I've alredy try using Variables like @Partial := @Partial + Amount but it seems that it first sum the first part (bills) and then the rest (payments)... like this...

```
From Customer 1
Type    CustomerId   Amount    Partial
B       1            100       100
P       1            -100      200
B       1            100       200
P       1            -100      100
```

it seems that first sum everything from bills and then start subtraction... anyone knows how to solve it?

********** // update  // ****************

here original query ...

(SELECT  'Bill' as cType   , b.type, b.tal , 'Customer', b.number , b.date , b.subtot, b.tax, IF(b.type='CA' or b.type='CB' or b.type='CC' or b.type='CX',b.total*-1,b.total) as total  FROM bills b WHERE b.idcustomer='000140') UNION ALL
(SELECT  'Payment' as cType, 'CO'  , '1'   , ''    , c.idcash , c.date , 0       ,0     , -c.amount FROM cash c WHERE c.idcustomer='000140' and ( c.type='CO' or c.type='DM') ) order by date asc;

this brings something like this

Bill    FX  1   Customer    9   2011-02-25  0.00    0.00    100.00

Payment CO  1       37  2011-03-04  0.00    0.00    -100.00

Bill    FX  1   Customer    616 2011-03-23  0.00    0.00    100.00

Payment CO  1       751 2011-04-12  0.00    0.00    -100.00

Bill    FX  1   Customer    1267    2011-04-27  0.00    0.00    100.00

Payment CO  1       1157    2011-05-10  0.00    0.00    -100.00

Bill    FX  1   Customer    1974    2011-05-26  0.00    0.00    100.00

Payment CO  1       1654    2011-06-08  0.00    0.00    -100.00

then When I try to sum patiars...using the following code

set @running_total=0;
(SELECT  'Bill' as cType   , b.type, b.tal , 'Customer', b.number , b.date , b.subtot, b.tax, IF(b.type='CA' or b.type='CB' or b.type='CC' or b.type='CX',b.total*-1,b.total) as total, ( @running_total := @running_total + total) AS RunningTotal  FROM bills b WHERE b.idcustomer='000140') UNION ALL
(SELECT  'Payment' as cType, 'CO'  , '1'   , ''    , c.idcash , c.date , 0       ,0     , -c.amount, ( @running_total := @running_total-c.amount) AS RunningTotal FROM cash c WHERE c.idcustomer='000140' and ( c.type='CO' or c.type='DM') ) order by date asc;

results...

Bill    FX  1   Customer    9   2011-02-25  0.00    0.00    100.00  100.00

Payment CO  1       37  2011-03-04  0.00    0.00    -100.00 1905.00

Bill    FX  1   Customer    616 2011-03-23  0.00    0.00    100.00  200.00

Payment CO  1       751 2011-04-12  0.00    0.00    -100.00 1805.00

Bill    FX  1   Customer    1267    2011-04-27  0.00    0.00    100.00  300.00

Payment CO  1       1157    2011-05-10  0.00    0.00    -100.00 1705.00

As you Can See seems to sum first all from bills and then start substraccion from payments...

Comment: What you want is a running total. Also, make sure you want to use `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I'd like to do it on the fly by the MySql Query .. I can do it App's code but maybe someone knows how to solve it.. I'll coppy alter the mysql query I'm using right now so it's easy to understand.

Comment: So you're aware `UNION` will remove duplicates? This is perfectly doable, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152503/running-total-for-each-entry-in-group-by), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359077/mysql-running-total-with-count).

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  You cannot do a running sum unless you have an indication of the ordering of the records.  Since there are two different sources, this would preferably be a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the only way I can think of doing this in MySQL, assuming that you have a time stamp for ordering the records.  If you have even a moderate amount of data, this may prove to be too inefficient:

```
select t.*,
       ((select sum(amount)
         from bills b
         where b.customerId = t.customerId and
               b.datetime <= t.datetime
        ) -
        (select sum(amount)
         from payments p
         where p.customerid = t.customerid and
               p.datetime <= t.datetime
        )
       ) as balance
from ((select 'B' as type, customerid, amount, datetime from bills b) union all
      (select 'P', customerid, amount, datetime from payments p)
     ) t
```

Comment: here I paste original query (not making a sum)

Comment: (SELECT  'Bill' as cType   , b.type, b.tal , b.name, b.number , b.date , b.subtot, b.tax, IF(b.type='CA' or b.type='CB' or b.type='CC' or b.type='CX',b.total*-1,b.total) as total  FROM bills b WHERE b.idcustomer='000140') UNION ALL
(SELECT  'Payment' as cType, 'CO'  , '1'   , ''    , c.idcash , c.date , 0       ,0     , -c.amount FROM cash c WHERE c.idcustomer='000140' and ( c.type='CO' or c.type='DM') ) order by date asc;

Comment: in original post you can see at the end of text... original query and result and query using running_total...

Comment: Keep in mind that result will always be beetwen 20-100 records (no performance expensive)